# List index is out of rage in search algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search

I'm trying to figure out what the problem in my code:
https://repl.it/@lerowhou/VerifiablePunyRobots

Could you please look at it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
n = int(input())

if n in arr:
    print("The element is there and it's position is %d" %arr.index(n))
else:
    print("The element is not in the list")
```

Comment: Im guessing the error occurs when you input a number greater that 17 ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. And I really don't know where is the mistake

Comment: it because of the while loop,
when you put while True, it goes into an infinite loop,
and since your program list length is 16, once it reaches the 16th pos, it says your list is out of range

Comment: actually python is designed as such that you dont need to search an element like that